# No feedback when installing plugins or updating

Tags: plugins, updates, installation

I've had this problem for a while now; I hoped that it would go away when I moved to my new host but it hasn't. Whenever I try to install or update a plugin or theme, or even update Wordpress, the page will simply say `downloading install package ...` but that is the only line that ever appears. If I leave it for a sufficient time the operation will complete successfully but Wordpress will only ever display the first step.

I'm running the latest version of Wordpress and everything is up to date. Does any one know why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How can you have the latest version of Wordpress while you are having problems with updating Wordpress? Make sure your folders have the right permission.

Comment: Yes, check all [folder permissions and owners](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) (preferable in the host control panel, or in FTP) and to replace all core files, please refer to this [troubleshoot guide](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list) on how to proceed.

Comment: Please [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and check your server logs if you have access to them.

Comment: @rrikesh I have the latest version because as I said, everything will update successfully, Wordpress just doesn't tell me when it's finished so I have to guess. I will check the folder permissions and server logs anyway

Comment: I've just checked and all the permissions seem to correct and there is nothing in the `error_log` file

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem I have found the culprit. I can't remember which one it was, but I had an outdated plugin enabled to gzip output. As soon as I disabled that, the problem went away.

I guess that is what you get for using outdated plugins (that hasn't been updated in over 2 years).

Answer (score 0):

For me it was as simple as adding

```
php_flag zlib.output_compression off
```

to my .htaccess file

***or*** adding

```
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
```

to wp-config.php... To bad it took me 4 hours to figure out :S